# Порядок применения функций и асинхронный код

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет! Столкнулось с такой проблемой, решение которой придумать не могу и гугл особо тоже не помогает.

Есть у меня фильтр на странице сайта, который получает данные при загрузке с другой страницы с аналогичного фильтра, также на этой же странице есть вывод объектов по этому фильтру, написанный на php.
Сейчас страница работает так, что сначала срабатывает на вывод php код, т.е. выводятся все объекты, т.к. значения опций у фильтра отсутствуют, а затем уже срабатывает js, после чего выводятся нужные элементы.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы сразу выводились нужные элементы без принудительного вывода всех элементов?

Заранее благодарна за все ваши ответы!

Comment: Реализовать фильтр на РНР

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо, но меня интересует как относительно данного условия все сделать

Comment: относительно данного условия сделать нельзя

Comment: Мдааа, @Ипатьев, ваша аватарка зарезервирована? При таких вопросах тоже хочется поставить себе такую!